# Resizing of the circular queue using dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, queue, dynamic-arrays

I'm analyzing the following code for a long time, but still, I'm not getting this one function's one line which is as follows:

```c
void ResizeQueue(struct DynArrayQueue* q) {
    int size = q->capacity;
    q->capactiy = q->capacity * 2;
    q->array = realloc(q->array, q->capacity);
    if (!q->array) {
        printf("Memory error");
        return;
    }

    // The doubt lines:
    if (q->front > q->rear) {
        for (int i = 0; i < q->front; i++) {
            q->array[i + size] = q->array[i];
        }
        q->rear = q->rear + size;
    }
}
```

My doubt to this above code is that, at what point in this dynamic array implementation of circular queue, the front become greater then the rear one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is because it is a circular buffer. Suppose a buffer is length 8, here are two scenes A and B where 4 data items are in the buffer, using `-` to indicate irrelevant data and `d` to indicate buffered data:

```
index   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7

A data  -   d   d   d   d   -   -   -
          begin        end

B data  d   d   -   -   -   -   d   d
           end                begin
```

So because - by definition of a circular buffer - the data wraps, the head might be lower than the tail, or the tail might be lower than the head.

Look what happens to buffer B when its length is doubled

```
index   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15
B data  d   d   -   -   -   -   d   d   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
           end                begin
```

Now it should be plain why the data needs to be moved so it is like this:

```
index   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15
B data  d   d   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   d   d
           end                                                begin
```

with the pointer or index adjusted accordingly.

Alternatively the data could be adjusted to look like this:

```
index   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15
B data  -   -   -   -   -   -   d   d   d   d   -   -   -   -   -   -
                              begin        end
```

Comment: very nicely explained, Got it, thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think your last diagram is correct - the code leaves "begin = front" in place at 6, and moves the data from 0..5 into 8..13

Comment: @AShelly the last line of the answer says "with the pointer or index adjusted accordingly."

Comment: ok, but in the OP's code the move loop is  `for(int i = 0 ; i<q->front ; i++)` - the first portion, not `for (i=q-<front;i<size;i++)` which would move the second portion..   I suppose an efficient implementation would chose whichever of those two ranges was smaller

Comment: @AShelly there is no data from 0..5, the data is initially from 6..1

Comment: @AShelly I have not referred to OP's code. I am explaining why there is a case where data needs to be moved. I don't know specifically what OP means by `front` and `rear` so I used different terms to illustrate the point.

Comment: @WeatherVane but the forloop is copying from index 0 to the the last index. I'm not getting your last diagram.

Comment: @AShelly the edit now shows the same part of the buffer moved as OP's code: there are two ways to adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

So the "front" is the read pointer, the next thing to be read.
The "rear" is the write pointer, the last thing inserted.

Any time a circular queue has more than `capacity` elements inserted, `rear` wraps around to the beginning, and `front > rear` becomes true.  That mechanism is what makes this a circular buffer.

If this resize code is called after that happens, it copies everything before the `front` read pointer into the new space at the end, and updates `rear` to point into that space.

(I think it would also be correct if it only copied elements upto `rear`. As  written, it's copying stale elements.)